# Change table to a longer format based on groups

Tags: r

I need to change the format of a table based on group values, but keeping the overall row values. Here is an example of the original table

```
Row  Atr1  Atr2 Atr3 ValA1   ValA2  ValA3  ValB1  ValB2 ValB3 ValC1 ValC2 ValC3
       1  21   SNV  T    yes     yes    100    yes    yes    98.1  no    yes    100
       2  43   SNp  C    yes     no     0      yes    no     0.65  yes   no       0
       3  43   SNV  C    yes     yes    100    yes    yes    99.35 yes   yes    100
       4  47   SNp  C    yes     yes    8.97   yes    no     0     yes   no       0
```

And I need to change it into

```
Row Atr1 Atr2 Atr3 Gr    Gr_Val1 Gr_Val2 Gr_Val3
   1  21 SNV  T    A       yes    yes        100
   2  21 SNV  T    B       yes    yes       98.1
   3  21 SNV  T    C       no     yes        100
   4  43 SNp  C    A       yes    no           0
   5  43 SNp  C    B       yes    no        0.65
   6  43 SNp  C    C       yes    no           0
   7  43 SNV  C    A       yes    yes        100
   8  43 SNV  C    B       yes    yes      99.35
   9  43 SNV  C    C       yes    yes        100
  10  47 SNp  C    A       yes    yes       8.97
  11  47 SNp  C    B       yes    no           0
  12  47 SNp  C    C       yes    no           0
```

So the initial group values are specified in each column, but should now be specified in each row. Any ideas on how to do this?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The following answer assumes that the columns that you want to convert are named `"Val[A-Z]+[0-9]+"`; that is "Val" followed any number of capital letters and then followed by any number of digits. In that case,

1. First `gather` the columns resulting in a `Key` column that contains the column names that are gathered.
2. `mutate` this `Key` column using string substitution to form two columns: `Gr` and `Gnum`. The `Gnum` column will be created to match the column names of your result (i.e., `Gr_Val1`, `Gr_Val2`, etc.).
3. Then, `group_by` `Gr` and `spread` using the `Gnum` as the key and the gathered values as the value.

Using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr) 
result <- df %>% gather("Key","Vals",-c(Row:Atr3)) %>% 
                 mutate(Gr=sub("[0-9]+","",sub("Val","",Key)),
                        Gnum=paste0("Gr_",sub("Val[A-Z]+","Val",Key))) %>% 
                 select(-Key) %>% 
                 group_by(Gr) %>% 
                 spread(Gnum,Vals)
```

The `result` is as expected:

```
print(result)
##Source: local data frame [12 x 8]
##Groups: Gr [3]
##
##     Row  Atr1   Atr2   Atr3    Gr Gr_Val1 Gr_Val2 Gr_Val3
##*  <int> <int> <fctr> <fctr> <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>
##1      1    21    SNV      T     A     yes     yes     100
##2      1    21    SNV      T     B     yes     yes    98.1
##3      1    21    SNV      T     C      no     yes     100
##4      2    43    SNp      C     A     yes      no       0
##5      2    43    SNp      C     B     yes      no    0.65
##6      2    43    SNp      C     C     yes      no       0
##7      3    43    SNV      C     A     yes     yes     100
##8      3    43    SNV      C     B     yes     yes   99.35
##9      3    43    SNV      C     C     yes     yes     100
##10     4    47    SNp      C     A     yes     yes    8.97
##11     4    47    SNp      C     B     yes      no       0
##12     4    47    SNp      C     C     yes      no       0
```